# Add different values to each of multiple vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I know that I can select multiple specific vertices by id in a single step, for example (using gremlin-python syntax):

```
g.V([1, 2, 3]).next()
>>> [v[1], v[2], v[3]]
```

How can I then add a property with different values to each of these selected items? For example, I would like that:

- Vertex 1 has property 'x' with value 'a'
- Vertex 2 has property 'x' with value 'b'
- Vertex 3 has property 'x' with value 'c'

So I'd like to be able to say something like:

```
g.V([1, 2, 3]).<add property 'x' with values ['a', 'b', 'c']>.next()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [choose()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#choose-step) to accomplish something like that which will give you if-then-else type branching. Using the modern toy graph that ships with TinkerPop distributions:

```
gremlin> g.V(1,2,3).
......1>   choose(id()).
......2>     option(1, property('switch','a')).
......3>     option(2, property('switch','b')).
......4>     option(3, property('switch','c')).iterate()
gremlin> g.V(1,2,3).
......1>   project('id','switch').
......2>     by(id).
......3>     by('switch')
==>[id:1,switch:a]
==>[id:2,switch:b]
==>[id:3,switch:c]
```

As of TinkerPop 3.3.3, you could also do something like this which uses a side-effect:

```
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('x',[1:'a',2:'b',3:'c']).
......1>   V(1,2,3).as('v').
......2>     property('switch', select('x').
......3>                        select(select('v').id()))
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.V(1,2,3).
......1>   project('id','switch').
......2>     by(id).
......3>     by('switch')
==>[id:1,switch:a]
==>[id:2,switch:b]
==>[id:3,switch:c]
```

You need 3.3.3+ because you need the ability to `select()` runtime generated keys which was only added in that version.

I don't think you can use the key of the `Map` of "x" to handle the lookup of the vertex without a lambda (maybe i'm not thinking of something simple), so unfortunately you have to specify the ids twice, but you could parameterize that pretty easily because you just need to construct the `Map` and then grab the `.keys()` from it to give to `V()`.

Comment: Thanks - this is a good answer for a small number of options, but it doesn't scale to the long lists I'm hoping to use.

Comment: updated answer based on comment - how does that look now?

Comment: Thanks - this definitely looks like the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately I'm not getting it to work in gremlin-python (server and python module at 3.3.3), perhaps because of the way I'm providing the mapping:
`g.withSideEffect('x',[(1, 'a') , (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]).V([1, 2, 3]).as_('v').property('switch', select('x').select(select('v').id())).next()
>>> GremlinServerError: 500: The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[1]->[SelectOneStep(last,x), TraversalSelectStep([SelectOneStep(last,v), IdStep])]` I'll keep trying, unless someone can spot what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: the side-effect should be a `Dictionary`, so in python i would have done `{1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}`